# How to hide part of image if the image length is too long for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, image

I am having trouble in re sizing the image when the image is too long . I am using a lsider for my mobile website . Most of the images are longer in width so they are mapped properly and my content does not go too much down . But when there is image which is longer in height i want that a padding should appear in portrait view and only center part of the image should be visible

Comment: Are you using media queries?. I didn't vote down this question, but if you want people to help you, you should post some code here, add a jsfiddle.net and explain clearly what you tried and what works and doesn't: whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="ok">
<img src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

css:
    #ok{
    Width:auto; height:400px;overflow:hidden;
    }
    #ok img{
    Width:200px;
    Height:auto;
    }

the above code is an example for image with the width of 200px and height is limited to 400px. If image overflowed or oversized the box hidden the area which overflowed.